# Disjoint unions in React.Component props

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I recently stumbled across the `disjoint unions` from flow-js (https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#disjoint-unions-) and tried to use them in my `React.Component` props.

The base idea was that I have a set of props that always needs to be set and according to a property, some other field also needs to have a content.

In my example, I wanted to have a `isEditable` flag that - if it's true - requires also the field `uploadUrl` to be set. If `isEditable` is false, `uploadUrl` must be null.

```
// Base properties
type OverallProps = { imageUrl: string, username: string };

// Disjoint unions
type IsPlainProps = { isEditable: false, uploadUrl: null };
type IsEditableProps = { isEditable: true, uploadUrl: string };

// My Props
type Props = OverallProps & (IsPlainProps | IsEditableProps);
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this setup working and I don't know why.

I isolated the scenario to this small snippet:
https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAPIBuWUyANnwAKxMOgC8cAN504cUMgDmWAKpQ+ALjioYUYADsFAGhlwArqh57kILJu26DxgL71GLNgElUgvsn3CIUTgJaVlgVABRABNgGGQAIz5bOAJ+C2NZUzA+CGQo1Q04PVMBZ1dmVjgvaNiEpICgkJNwmrjE5J1TLAyzbNz8tTsdfSM6FwYKtgbxDm5eAWm4ADI4AAovHz89RYAfKsiYtvqRVABKV1xfVHQAZRIsGAALEbgsAA8YLD0o9Gw8GAAdIJTJQAMIkSB6L4wAA80wAfFIxgxcBA9No5Adau1NPEIBA+ME4J0sK4YXcbE8Xs0QIoVGoxAAiBK4RkmcyWaxYJkcqBWGxssJYo7cyQtQ51LBOdl9PIFMRi4WSuAAfjgjKyOTlakZcE0xQE0oA9PCgA

Can anyone out there explain to me why I get the following error?

```
<Something 
^ Cannot create `Something` element because: Either boolean [1] is incompatible with boolean literal `false` [2] in property `isEditable`. Or boolean [1] is incompatible with boolean literal `true` [3] in property `isEditable`.

References:
23: const isEditable: bool = true;
                      ^ [1]
9:   isEditable: false,
                 ^ [2]
14:   isEditable: true,
                  ^ [3]
```

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because true and false are values.

And you are defining data types, for example doing it like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

type OverallProps = {
  imageUrl: string,
  username: string,
};

type IsPlainProps = {
  isEditable: bool,
  uploadUrl: ?string,
};

type IsEditableProps = {
  isEditable: bool,
  uploadUrl: string,
};

type Props = OverallProps & (IsPlainProps | IsEditableProps);

class Something extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
}

const isEditable: bool = true;

<Something 
  imageUrl="abc"
  username="username"
  isEditable={isEditable}
  uploadUrl={isEditable ? "uploadUrl" : null}
/>
```

Are you still struggling with this issue? To change the type of your data structure based on the given value, maybe casting is the right solution? https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/